# fast search-within-text in SQL Server (fulltext not good enough)

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am using fulltext indexing in SQL Server 2000 and 2012. It is working great, except that users need to be able to search for ' * term * ' and not just 'term * ' (that is, the search needs to return results that contain the search term, not just begin with the search term).

From what I read and researched, this is not possible in SQL Server.

Since this is a requirement, and using the LIKE operator instead of full text is just too slow, I am thinking about breaking up each value into words, and creating a special table that contains each word twice - once normal, once reversed - and a foreign key to the relevant item.

This is the only way I can see to accomplish decent speeds.

Has anyone done this? Does anyone know of any other solution? Is it maybe possible to control the index itself, adding the reverse values to it, without actually creating a column that contains them?

Comment: You can always try to use Solr for example as a separated indexer and search engine, search with it and retrieve the rest of data you need from sql server.

Comment: Thanks for this advice lavrik, that was another solution I was considering. I am surprised to know that solr is so fast being that it is written in Java... I will definitely look into it.

Comment: Also check out any Lucene-based search engine. Lucene supports wildcards at the start of the term and it's very fast. (FYI Solr is Lucene-based.)